# YAML as failsafe file dump format (using pyyaml)?

Tags: python, yaml

I'd like to dump structured data (mostly tabular with some additional meta data) to a file as input for another program. However, some data fields can be arbitrary unicode data. Do you know if PyYaml is a failsafe solution (which for example escapes all problem cases) or which other simple file based solution would you suggest? I'm afraid that special characters break the format or the parser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any good serializer will handle arbitrary Unicode, by converting it into Unicode point references.

With YAML:

```
>>> yaml.dump({'foo': u'τί ἐστίν; 統一碼!!! ✢✪✺'})
'{foo: "\\u03C4\\u1F77 \\u1F10\\u03C3\\u03C4\\u1F77\\u03BD; \\u7D71\\u4E00\\u78BC!!! \\u2722\\u272A\\\n    \\u273A"}\n'
```

With JSON:

```
>>> json.dumps({'foo': u'τί ἐστίν; 統一碼!!! ✢✪✺'})
'{"foo": "\\u03c4\\u1f77 \\u1f10\\u03c3\\u03c4\\u1f77\\u03bd; \\u7d71\\u4e00\\u78bc!!! \\u2722\\u272a\\u273a"}'
```

Comment: Firstly, commas are not a problem; quotes are, and of course, they are escaped. Secondly, why couldn’t you just test it yourself in a prompt?

Comment: For commas I can test. But a proof that any thinkable unicode character will work is harder by trying. Unicode isn't trivial. I had weird errors sometimes. Who knows if some very special character won't translate to that kind of point reference?

Comment: @Gerenuk: yep, bugs in software happen. If that’s your concern, try writing your own serializer, then proving it with a formal method.

Comment: Actually I don't mean bugs, but known issues. If the above `\\u####` parts theoretically cover everything I can encounter in some unicode data, then the answer is "failsafe". If it is known, that are unicode character not covered, then the answer is "not failsafe".

Comment: Here is the YAML spec: http://yaml.org/spec/1.2/spec.html#Characters and it says quite clearly what is and is not allowed in the output. I’m pretty sure some thought has been put into that section. If PyYAML doesn’t adhere to that, I’d call it a bug. You can check if such a bug is known in the PyYAML issue tracker.